# loaderror: 126: the specified module could not be found. "windows7" sqlite3_native.so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Platform:

```
Windows 7 64 bit
Rails 4.1.6
gem 2.2.2
```

Followed the installation steps for compilation of native gem. 
Ran `configure` then `make` then `make install` using the utility in the devkit.

Gem install went fine:

```
C:\Sites>gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby  -- --with-sqlite3-include=C:\DevKit\home\hivoltage sqlite-autoconf --with-sqlite3-lib=C:\DevKit\home\hivoltage\sqlite-autoconf\.libs

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...

Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-include=C:\DevKit\home\hivoltage\sqlite-autoconf --with-sqlite3-lib=C:\DevKit\home\hivoltage\sqlite-autoconf\.libs'

This could take a while...

Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.9

Parsing documentation for sqlite3-1.3.9

Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.9

Done installing documentation for sqlite3 after 0 seconds

1 gem installed
```

Now the error is when I try to run a rake command:

```
C:\Sites\demo>rake db:migrate

rake aborted!

LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/sqlite3-1.3.9/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
C:/Sites/demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'C:/Sites/demo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.1/sqlite3_native C:/Sites/demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/demo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have also made sure the gemfile and gemfile.lock have the correct version listed.

Does anyone know why I cannot get this sqlite3 gem working with my rails project?